# Manifest architecture / os flags for linking different lib versions

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, linking, 64bit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a library X that builds differently for 64 and 32 bit systems and outputs the binaries to the subfolders unix32/lib and unix64/lib respectively.

For dependend packages I publish both the unix32 and the unix64 lib-path in the manifest of X as follows:

When I link against this package on 64bit systems the linker puts out a warning about skipping incompatible libs. (naturally this is about the 32 bit version)

Would it be somehow possible to add a switch in library X's manifest much like the existing "os"-switch that would allow me to specify the appropriate directory for the given architecture and thereby turn the warning off?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11510/manifest-architecture-/-os-flags-for-linking-different-lib-versions/) by [Simon Lynen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1211/simon-lynen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

got it:

```
 <export>
<cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags=" -L${prefix}/unix`getconf LONG_BIT`/lib -lX"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Simon Lynen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1211/simon-lynen/) with karma: 116 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5